# d3.js html table – parsing values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm creating a table in d3 from data exported from Excel as tsv. The code below is working pretty well, but there are a couple of parsing selecting problems I can't seem to solve.

Firstly, I want to parse all of the numerical data as numbers, using forEach. My table has four columns, the first is string data and the others are all numbers, but I can't omit the first column from my parsing.

Secondly, where negative numbers occur, the client needs them displayed in brackets e.g. (12,345) and I can't wrangle the d3 formatting to strip the minus sign and add the brackets.

This third point is now solved.
Thirdly, I'd love to be able to have an additional column which isn't displayed, but is accessed to apply a class to the tr for certain rows so that we can style them in css. The code below is appending a unique class to each row, but that only works if I know in advance which rows have a certain style. I need the client to be able to select which rows to apply a style to.

```
d3.tsv("data/index.tsv", function(data) {
// the columns you'd like to display
var columns = ["Trading Summary", "Budget", "Actual", "Variance"];

var table = d3.select("#currentMonth").append("table"),
    thead = table.append("thead"),
    tbody = table.append("tbody");

// append the header row
thead.append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(columns)
    .enter()
    .append("th")
        .text(function(column) { return column; }); 


// create a row for each object in the data
var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("tr")
    .attr("class", function(d, i) { return "indexRow" + i; });

// create a cell in each row for each column
var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
    .data(function(row) {
        return columns.map(function(column) {
            return {column: column, value: row[column]};
        });
    })
    .enter()
    .append("td")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return d.column; })
        .text(function(d) { return d.value; });

});
```

I hope I've explained that relatively clearly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Data sample:

```
Trading Summary Budget  Actual  Variance
SALES   200,000 104,374 (95,626)
LESS COST OF GOODS SOLD 24,000  (23,563)    (47,563)
LESS MANUFACTURING COSTS    123,550 52,153  (71,397)
    147,550 28,589  (118,961)
```

Comment: Please include sample data...

Comment: I've managed to sort out the third point, I was just referencing the extra column incorrectly.